# Trouble importing .dat files in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi all I am trying to import data from the openflights website but I am having trouble since the files are in .dat format. On top of that I keep getting permission denied when the query tries to read the file.

```
CREATE TABLE Airlines(
Airline_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Airline_Name Varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Alias Varchar(255),
IATA Varchar(2),
ICAO Varchar(3),
Callsign Varchar(255),
Country Varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
Active varchar(255)
);

copy Airlines from 'C:/Users/1059ism/Desktop/airlines.dat'
delimiter ',';
```

Also is there a way to tell the query to recognise a specific notation that the table uses for null values
From openflights:

> The special value \N is used for "NULL" to indicate that no value is available, and is understood automatically by MySQL if imported.

Comment: ".dat" isn't a format, it's just a filename. It sounds like it's probably tab-separated or comma-separated data. Have a look at the first few lines, and take a look at the documentation for `COPY`. You might need to use `WITH (FORMAT CSV)`.

Comment: Permission denied on the file happens because the file is read by the backend process of the postgresql service which runs under a different user. On linus of postgres on windows often "Network service" make sure this user has access to the file.

Comment: From PostgreSQL documentation: ["The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)